# Handshake failure when using jconsole with ssl

Tags: java, ssl, jconsole

I am trying to connect to an application remotely using jconsole.  Without SSL my configuration works with no issues.

I have created a public key on the server I wish to access:

```
sudo keytool -keystore broker.ks -alias broker -genkey -keyalg RSA
```

I have then exported the certificate:

```
sudo keytool -export -alias broker -keystore broker.ks -file broker_cert.crt
```

Client side I create a trust store and import the certificate:

```
-import -alias broker -keystore broker.ts -file broker_cert.crt
```

I then launch my broker server side as follows:

```
java \
-Xms1024M \
-Xmx1024M \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/etc/activemq/jmx.password \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=/etc/activemq/jmx.access \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \
-jar broker.jar \
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/etc/activemq/broker.ks \
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password
```

As I mentioned, the password configuration works properly as I am able to connect when setting jmxremote.ssl to false.

Client side I then launch jconsole like so:

```
jconsole -J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/etc/activemq/broker.ts -J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password -J-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/etc/activemq/logging.properties
```

When trying to connect to the server the logs give me the following error:

```
failed to connect: java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is: 
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

To elaborate on this, my certificates are definately set-up correctly.  Server side I can do in /etc/activemq:

```
keytool -list -keystore broker.ks
```

And recieve:

```
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

broker, 01-May-2012, PrivateKeyEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): 30:55:60:4A:B5:85:D0:C5:2C:E9:DD:AD:1E:92:BE:6E
```

Client side in /etc/activemq I can type:

```
keytool -list -keystore broker.ks
```

And recieve:

```
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

broker, May 3, 2012, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): 30:55:60:4A:B5:85:D0:C5:2C:E9:DD:AD:1E:92:BE:6E
```

As you can see the certificate fingerprints match.  What is even more frustrating is that when I start jconsole, I can put a completely bogus path in `-J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=<boguspathhere>` yet I recieve exactly the same error as when I put the correct one which is  `/etc/activemq/broker.ts` - I would expect the logs to at least tell me whether it has found the trust store or not!  Instead of just giving

```
failed to connect: java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection     establishment; nested exception is: 
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

grrrr

Comment: It is clear indication that certificates are not imported properly. Make sure certificates are showing up and JAVA_HOME settings.

Comment: Why Java_Home?  I am using an explicit path in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the mystery has been solved and has been stupidity on my part:

```
java \
-Xms1024M \
-Xmx1024M \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/etc/activemq/jmx.password \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=/etc/activemq/jmx.access \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \
-jar broker.jar \
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/etc/activemq/broker.ks \
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password
```

The last two system property arguments get ignored because -jar broker.jar is run before them.  In order to have fixed this all I needed to do was write:

```
java \
-Xms1024M \
-Xmx1024M \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/etc/activemq/jmx.password \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=/etc/activemq/jmx.access \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/etc/activemq/broker.ks \
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password \
-jar broker.jar
```

Doh!